# I get "function is not defined" when I move a Javascript function from in-line code, to a separate js file

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I am trying to make a very simple thing work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/test.js" type="text/js"></script>
<button onclick="test()" type="submit">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

With js/test.js being found by the browser and containing:

```
function test() {
    alert("test");
}
```

When opening the page and clicking the button, nothing happens and I can see in the console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test:7)
```

I have tried to move the script import above or under the button, or in the header.
I have tried to use "window.setlocale = function" in my js file.
I have tried to put nothing in the test method.
I checked for errors with JSLint (there is no error).

When I check the source, I can see the js file and the browser opens it when I click on it.

The only way I can get the Javascript to work is to write it inline...

Maybe the issue is with my environment?

In order to run this, I use an Apache server, and it is configured to serve this on localhost:8077. I works fine so far.
I use Laravel 7.10, PHP 7.4... working fine. To run this I created a simple route, that shows the view (a simple index.blade.php) with the HTML content copy/pasted above. It displays fine on "http://localhost:8077/test", no problem.

I also tried to use the laravel notation

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/test.js') }}" type="text/js"></script>
```

but it gives the same result.

I also have the PHP debugbar (a Laravel plugin) active, and it does not show any error. The view is properly loaded and displayed.

Also, I use PHPStorm, and it does not detect any issue.

It's been 2 days and I cannot makes this seemingly extremely basic thing to work, please help me m(_ _)m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script type is wrong. Use `application/javascript` in your `script` element to make your javascript work - or better yet, remove the `type` attribute and let browsers auto-detect the type:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/test.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
    <button onclick="test()" type="submit">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Without `type` attribute:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/test.js"></script>
    <button onclick="test()" type="submit">Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you so much, you saved my day!! This type came along as I copy pasted  from the default Laravel app.js import on the default welcome page... Copy pasting is dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add script tag to header tag. like this

> `<head>
>             <script type="text/javascript" src="path/to/script.js"></script>
>             <!--other script and also external css included over here-->
>       </head>`

Comment: Yes, I confirmed the path is right, I could click the path (from the html source) and see the content of my js file being displayed in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the function name in js/test.js

```
function() {
    alert("test");
}
```

Comment: I tried, despite my IDE warning me the Javascript was wrong, and it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Please add the js file as a reference in the header section of your core file. External referencing.